# Match all elements having class name starting with a specific string

Tags: css

Is it possible to use a "wildcard" for elements having a class name starting with a specific string in CSS3?

Example:

```
<div class="myclass-one"></div>
<div class="myclass-two"></div>
<div class="myclass-three"></div>
```

and then magically set all the above `div`s to red in one go:

```
.myclass* { color: #f00; }
```

Comment: `[class^='myclass-'], [class*=' myclass-'] { color: red }`

Comment: `[^="start"]  [*="contain"]  [$="ends"]`  ( ^ * $  rules are from Regular expressions )

Answer (score 705):

The following should do the trick:

```
div[class^='myclass'], div[class*=' myclass']{
    color: #F00;
}
```

---

Edit: Added wildcard (`*`) as suggested by David

Comment: Only if the class beginning with `myclass` is also the *first* class-name contained within the `class` attribute. You might want to try [`div[class*=myclass] { /* ...stuff... */}`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

Comment: even better; to prevent collision `div[class*=' myclass'],div[class^='myclass']`

Comment: agreed, I was about to edit the white-space prefaced version into my comment (when I remembered it), then I saw you'd already added that detail! =)

Comment: Schweet! I always forget about the attribute thing (probably because it looks so ugly.)

What I -still- don't understand is this:

According to the W3C page: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp the syntax is:

    div[class*="test"]

Yet, it -seems- to work like this, with no 'element' specified:

   [class*="test"]

...which I don't get. IOW, -why- does this work? (I'm not complaining, I like it -better-!) I just don't want to start using it and find out that it's a bug that later gets 'fixed'.

Any ideas?

THANKS!

---JC

Comment: @jchwebdev--it is not a bug. The attribute selector is just like any other selector (it can be used as a "stand alone"). It is no different that `.myClass` potentially being used with `div.myClass` instead. The attribute selector can stand alone (matching any elements that meet that criteria) or be narrowed to specific element. So don't worry about it being odd to have `[class*="myClass"]` all by itself.

Comment: `*` will include `^`, duplicity.

Comment: @mystrdat no, notice the space in the `*` version. You don't want to match `x-myclass` by using only the `*` version without a space.

Comment: Not sure why you've overqualified with `div` - or why you didn't include the `-`

Comment: Thanks , I used it like this  **div:not([class*=myclass-])**  in another case

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what this code is actually doing

Comment: for completeness sake, use `div[class$=myclass]` to match for class names ending with `myclass`

Answer (score 26):

It's not a direct answer to the question, however I would suggest in most cases to simply set multiple classes to each element:

```
<div class="myclass one"></div>
<div class="myclass two"></div>
<div class="myclass three"></div>
```

In this way you can set rules for all `myclass` elements and then more specific rules for `one`, `two` and `three`.

```
.myclass { color: #f00; }

.two { font-weight: bold; }

etc.
```

Comment: By using multiple classes rather than looking for prefixes, you also save yourself a few battles with specificity and selector speed. Attribute selectors are slow, but also are really very specific compared to just classes. +1

Comment: I get it. I'm using WordPress, which assigns similar named classes based on 'slug'. So the attribute solution is -way- easier than trying to add additional classes to each relevant page.

Comment: @TWiStErRob Yeah, imagine how I feel - I got -4 and answered FIRST, this guy said the exact same thing AFTER and gets upvotes haha.

Comment: @Andy - This is not at all the same as your answer, unless it has been changed. It's almost the opposite actually.

Comment: @TWiStErRob - while this is good practice, - using a block modifier approach, it in no way answers the question.

Comment: @sheriffderek why is it the "opposite"? Both have general classes for base and special classes for overrides. I agree that it's not a direct answer (the magic attribute matching I'm not too fond of), but I don't see any logical difference between the two answers by Andy and James, only their rep level.

Comment: First off, they are `divs` - ok, that's in common... then in one answer there is a `myclass` - which says "all divs with myclass" - and then there is a modifier class of `class-1, class-2, class-3 etc... ` So - divs are square, myclass is round, class-1 is red .. this builds up 'cascading' styles as was intended. Your answer, @TWiStErRob - is too specific, too early - and is much less modular an reusable. It's basically backwards.

Comment: @sheriffderek I still don't see it. There's a 1:1 correspondence: `myclass`<->`another-class`, `one`<->`myclass-one` also you may need to be specific with `.generic.special` to increase the selector's specificity to apply overrides for color for example. (Not my answer, I just don't see the difference, and the votes feel unfair. Also the `div` comes from the question.)

Comment: I really can't understand why I got another downvote on this almost 3 years later (or why Andy is -5 for that matter).  I still stand by this answer, multiple classes is a much cleaner approach than partial matching a class attribute.  Sure there are reasons you might have to and Koen's answer answers that, but I guarentee plenty of people who found this question don't have a good excuse for not using multple classes.  And for the record, I'm sure my rep was considerably lower 3 years ago.

Comment: @sheriffderek can you explain why it's the OPPOSITE (lol I read that almost fell off my chair, one of us has to be drunk to not understand they are the same). What am I missing? 

And JamesMontagne you are correct, I still think it's the best solution too, hence why I stated the exact same thing you said, when I saw no other answers yet, however long ago this question was.

Comment: A square is a rectangle - but a rectangle is not a square.

Comment: They have the same outcome... http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/YyqybM?editors=110

Comment: `class="x a", class="x b", class="x c"` @Andy These answers are literally identical.

Comment: @WylliamJudd - Correct. Which is why the whole comments took off to begin with. The answers are identical, I submitted my answer first but was downvoted (originally) and this one was upvoted - hence all the confusion. But oh well as long as they help people in the future solve similar issues - great!

Comment: What if everything is dynamically generated?

Answer (score 5):

You can easily add multiple classes to divs... So:

```
<div class="myclass myclass-one"></div>
<div class="myclass myclass-two"></div>
<div class="myclass myclass-three"></div>
```

Then in the CSS call to the share class to apply the same styles:

```
.myclass {...}
```

And you can still use your other classes like this:

```
.myclass-three {...}
```

Or if you want to be more specific in the CSS like this:

```
.myclass.myclass-three {...}
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is *that* bad.  I would just edit another-class to be myclass... class="myclass myclass-one"

Comment: now its similar to the above

Comment: I did not see that thread above...

Comment: I still wouldn't give either of these answers too many points, because they don't answer the wildcard question.

Comment: Correct, it is similar to the one above, ironically it was posted first & got negative votes. Haha. Also, it's not a DIRECT answer, but an alternate solution that perhaps the original author didn't think about & probably the ideal solution in all scenarios in which you have full control over HTML & CSS.