# Select element that has a class that starts with a string

Tags: css, class

Is it possible to select a element that has a class that starts with a string?

There is

```
 .element[class^="icon-"]{
   ...
 }
```

but it fails when the class is preceded by another class or whatever :(

Comment: Your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352080/css-match-all-class-selectors-that-begin-with

Comment: can you add another html attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can!

```css
.element[class^='icon-'],
.element[class*=' icon-'] {
  ...
}
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/caio/mxUxR/.

Comment: This will, of course, fail if the class is preceded by any of the *other* valid whitespace characters: `\n`, `\r`, `\f`, and `\t`. Otherwise, the general idea is sound.

Comment: @zzzzBov yes, you know a solution to "fix" it?