# Match any css class beginning with string

Tags: css, css-selectors, match

I'm looking for a way in css to select any element with a class that matches the beginning of a string. I know about the [class*="string"] and [class^="string"] rules, but those aren't exactly what I'm looking for. ^= only matches the first class, so any preceding classes will break it. And *= looks for any part of the string, not just the beginning.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HiJjL

```
HTML:

<div class="asdf col-6">match</div>
<div class="col-6">match</div>
<div class="x-col-6">dont match</div>

CSS:

[class *= "col-"] {
    color:red;
}
[class ^= "col-"] {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

The pen illustrates the problem. The first selector is too broad, the second is too narrow. Of course I can work around this by using *= and being careful with my other class names, but I was curious if this is possible.

Comment: Look at the upvoted answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352080/match-all-class-selectors-that-begin-with). I think it might apply to your question.

Comment: @icemanind, you were right. i used a selector like this div[class^="col-"], div[class*=" col-"]

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
span[id^='string_'] {}
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="string_example">string example</span>
```

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: The answer fits the question, the problem is that the classes aren't well formatted. Clean up the class names and you'll get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know off such a possibility, but I also think it is not the right way. A better solution would be to add multiple classes to the element.

```
<div class="asdf col col-6">match</div>
<div class="col col-6">match</div>
<div class="x-col-6">dont match</div>
```

This way, you can tell that that div is a 'col' (column?) and more specifically, it is a 'col-6'.