# CSS: Class name selector- name starts with

Tags: html, css

I have two different type of class names. The first are named `color-*`. For example:

```
color-red
color-blue
color-green
```

I also have class names `hover-color-*`

```
hover-color-red
hover-color-blue
hover-color-green
```

I am attempting to make a css rule for the default hyperlink color:

```
a:not([class*='color-']) {
    color: #3498db;
}
```

This is fine, however if a hyperlink exists like this:

```
<a href="#" class="hover-color-green">Link</a>
```

In this instance, the hyperlink should keep the default hyperlink color and only the hover color should be overridden, however because of the rule `class*='color-'` and the fact I only specified the hover color, the hyperlink is not given a normal color (#3498db).

Is there any way to update this rule so that it only triggers if the class name begins with `color-`? (so, `ANYTHING-color-` would not apply)

Comment: you need to learn about css specifity and order - this way you can set the default colour at the top using just `a {}` then overwrite them with your specific classes - this way you don't need to bother with all this not and attribute includes

Comment: @Pete Then my color rules instead of looking like `.color-red, .hover-color-red:hover {` would also have to include hyperlinks too: `.color-red, .hover-color-red:hover, a.color-red, a.hover-color-red:hover {`... makes for a lot more content in the css file.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal working code example, to display what the issue is. You seem to be over complicating things.

Comment: again, read my previous comment - `.color-red` trumps `a` so you would not need `a.color-red` - learn the basics and it will stand you in good stead further down the line when you may need something as complicated as you are trying to do, but usually, I find it's about the way of think about what you are trying to achieve and there will always be a simple way to reorder things

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The selector you are using `*=` matches any attribute **containing** that string.

Instead, you want `^=`, which matches any attribute **beginning** with that string.

A combination would work best:

`a[class^='color-'], a[class*=' color-'] { ... }`

See [MDN page on CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and
[this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352080/match-all-class-selectors-that-begin-with).

Comment: That matches a *class attribute* which begins with `color-`, not a *class*. So it wouldn't work for `class="another-class color-green"`.

Comment: But then the color class has to be the first class named for each element... very difficult to control.

Comment: @Quentin: yes, that is a limitation. I see the issue.

Comment: @Quentin: I have updated my answer to handle that limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it in another way. Don't change whatever not contain color inside class name. First change all `a` to what you want:

```
a {
    color: yellow;
}

a:hover {
    color: orange;
}
```

then you can overwrite them with:

```
a.color-red{...}
a.color-blue{...}
a.color-green{...}
a.hover-color-red{...}
a.hover-color-blue{...}
a.hover-color-green{...}
```

and now you can use it like:

```
<a ... class="color-red hover-color-blue">test</a>
```

**Don't make it complicated. It can work perfectly and also in the future you can maintain your styles more easily.**

If you want to use it everywhere just select it like:

```
.color-red{...}
.color-blue{...}
.color-green{...}
.hover-color-red{...}
.hover-color-blue{...}
.hover-color-green{...}
```

see the example here:

```css
a {
  color: gray;
}
a:hover {
  color: orange;
}
.color-red, .color-red-hover:hover {
  color: red;
}    
.color-blue, .color-blue-hover:hover {
   color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a class="color-red color-blue-hover" href="#">Red</a>
<a class="color-blue color-red-hover" href="#">Blue</a>
<a href="#">Normal</a>
```

Comment: Then my color rules instead of looking like `.color-red, .hover-color-red:hover {` would also have to include hyperlinks too: `.color-red, .hover-color-red:hover, a.color-red, a.hover-color-red:hover {`... makes for a lot more content in the css file. The color rules can be applied to `<p>`, `<span>`, `<div>` etc

Comment: @JROB You don't need to do that. you can use it just with `.color-red, .hover-color-red:hover {`. look at this example I just made http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJvgrJ