# can I have css selector to match widget-logs and widget-chart like widget-* {...}

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-selectors, widget

I am building a widgetized dashboard in which I am rendering widgets like widget-logs, widget-chart & widget-list etc.

I want to apply common styling to widgets like given below which doesn't work but would like to know is something else I can use for my use case:-

```
widget-* {
   header { font-weight: bold; }
}
```

instead of:-

```
widget-logs, 
widget-chart,
widget-list {
   header { font-weight: bold; }
}
```

Comment: of course: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832255/css-class-name-selector-name-starts-with/41832387#41832387

Comment: my markup doesn't have a class so exploring does we can have something like widget-* {...}

<widgets-layout>
  <widget-wrapper ng-repeat="(key, value) in dataset">
    <ng-compile-component>
      <widget-log></widget-log>
    </ng-compile-component>

    <ng-compile-component>
      <widget-chart></widget-chart>
    </ng-compile-component>

    <ng-compile-component>
      <widget-list></widget-list>
    </ng-compile-component>
  </widget-wrapper>
</widgets-layout>

Comment: @Temani Afif I am aware of attribute selector I am looking for something similar to CSS tag selectors like widget-* {...} instead of having classes on each element.

Comment: so you need to make your question more clear and include the code inside the question ... by the way what you want is not possible

Answer (score 0):

```
[class^='widget']{ /* class name starts with widget */

}
[class$='widget']{ /* class name ends with widget */

}
[class*='widget']{ /* contains widget in class name */

}
```