# jquery toggle between ID's based on element attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this

```
$(".picker").click(function(e) {
    var imgID = $(this).attr("data-imgID");
    $('body').addClass('picker-' + imgID);
});

<span class="taPicker" data-imgID="0"></span>
<span class="taPicker" data-imgID="1"></span>
<span class="taPicker" data-imgID="2"></span>
```

i want to toggle between generic classes on body element, for example if you click on .picker i want to add a unique class to body element based on the data-imgID attribute

But, how can i prevent the duplication's? for example if you click on another .picker i want to remove the previous class and add a new one

Comment: Use the remove class function with a partial selector so it remove all the classes starting with `picker-` before adding the new one. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832255/css-class-name-selector-name-starts-with

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery removeClass wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644299/jquery-removeclass-wildcard)

Comment: @GillesC don't think you can use a wildcard with `.removeClass` - the link you've provided is for a selector, not an argument to removeClass - you can however use a function as shown here: [jQuery removeClass wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644299/jquery-removeclass-wildcard)  (so the principle is the same)

Comment: @freedomn-m Yeah can't use wildcard, haven't use jQuery in over 10 years so should have check the documentation first. But it doesn't just take function either, it can take a list of classes too as a string or an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you could do something like this:

```js
var selectedClass = null;
$(".taPicker").click(function(e) {
  var imgID = $(this).attr("data-imgID");
  $('body').addClass('picker-' + imgID);
  if (selectedClass != null) {
    $('body').removeClass(selectedClass);
  }
  selectedClass = 'picker-' + imgID;
});
```

```css
body.picker-0 {
  background-color: pink;
}

body.picker-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

body.picker-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="taPicker" data-imgID="0">click 0</span>
<span class="taPicker" data-imgID="1">click 1</span>
<span class="taPicker" data-imgID="2">click 2</span>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3x7tq2hb/)

Comment: Just to point out, the click handler will have to be set on `.taPicker`, otherwise this won't work.

Comment: Converted to a snippet, no need for a fiddle

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to determined the classes which need to be removed on each subsequent update. To this end, you can use a function which parses the current classes and removes any class which contains `picker-`, before setting the new class.

Here's what the JS code would look like:

```
function getPickerClasses(index, className) {
  return className.split(' ').filter((classItem) => classItem.includes('picker-'));
}

$(".taPicker").click(function(e) {
    var imgID = $(this).attr("data-imgID");
    
    $('body').removeClass(getPickerClasses).addClass('picker-' + imgID);
});
```

This way, before setting the new class, the old one is removed.
Have a look at this fiddle to see the code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/0u24a1g3/

Answer (score 1):

It can be done without adding extra global variable

```js
$(".taPicker").click(function(e) {
  var imgID = $(this).attr("data-imgID");
  $('body').removeClass(function() {
    return (this.className.match(/picker-./g) || []).join(' ');
  });
  $('body').addClass('picker-' + imgID);
});
```

```css
body.picker-0 {
  background-color: pink;
}

body.picker-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

body.picker-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="taPicker" data-imgID="0">click 0</span>
<span class="taPicker" data-imgID="1">click 1</span>
<span class="taPicker" data-imgID="2">click 2</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the original class(es) of `body` in a variable at DOM ready then use `.removeClass()` before re-adding back the original class plus the one based on the clicked element.

```js
$(".taPicker").click(function(e) {
    var imgID = $(this).attr("data-imgID");
    var picker = $('body').attr("class").match(/picker-\d+/g) || [];
    $('body').removeClass(picker).addClass('picker-' + imgID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="original">
<span class="taPicker" data-imgID="0">0</span>
<span class="taPicker" data-imgID="1">1</span>
<span class="taPicker" data-imgID="2">2</span>
</body>
```

Comment: There could  be a case where another body class is added somewhere else, then after next click on `picker` that would be ignored