# Change common CSS tag name

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I have this piece of code showing the price, I want to hide it. I can display: none; on the price tag but then it is not showing anywhere, in the cart etc.

So I need to display none on the tag rnb_price_unit_*number* but I can't go through and do that for every item.

Is there a way to select all of the tags beginning with rnb_price_unit_ ?
I thought rnb_price_unit_ * {display:none;} might work but it isn't.

Thanks[image of inspect for better view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voZ4i.png)

Comment: Welcome tot StackOverflow. Please add html code or make a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: Class name selector- name starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832255/css-class-name-selector-name-starts-with)

Comment: Can you provide the site link ?

Comment: site is toolsonthemove.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this using the `CSS [attribute^=value] Selector`

It would look something like this:

```css
span[class^="amount rnb_price_unit_"] {
  background: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<span class="amount rnb_price_unit_30">from
  <span>something</span>
</span>
<span class="amount rnb_price_unit_40">from
  <span>something</span>
</span>
```

Further details about this selector can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp

Comment: Yea this worked. Massive thanks for the quick response too! Thanks!!