# How to select divs that starts with 'paged-' and then a number on different pages?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a dynamic page that displays multiple pages and has a class that starts with 'paged-' and the number of that page. I want to remove a div with SASS when it's on the page 2 and beyond like this:

```
    .paged-2, .paged-3, .paged-4, .paged-5, .paged-100{
      .removeonpagetwoandso{
        display: none;
      }
    }
```

But I don't want to write from paged-2 to paged-100 since I don't know how many pages it will have in the future.

[This doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352080/match-all-class-selectors-that-begin-with):

```
    div[class^='paged'], div[class*='paged-']{
              .removeonpagetwoandso{
                display: none;
              }
    }
```

EDIT: Added HTML Structure

Page 1:

```
<body class="home"> 
 <div class="removeonpagetwoandso">Home Page 1 Only</div>
</body>
```

Page 2 and so:

```
<body class="home paged-2"> 
 <div class="removeonpagetwoandso">Home Page 1 Only</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Given that those selectors a valid, you need to provide a _verifiable sample_, and here is how-to: [mcve]

Comment: Please check my updated answer, now that I can see your HTML I found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

SASS compile

```
div[class^='paged'],
div[class*='paged-']{
  .removeonpagetwoandso{
    display: none;
    }
  }
```

to

```
div[class^=paged] .removeonpagetwoandso,
div[class*=paged-] .removeonpagetwoandso {
  display: none;
}
```

In your case

```
div[class^='paged-'] {
    .removeonpagetwoandso {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

is enough. It is compiled to

```
div[class^=paged-] .removeonpagetwoandso {
  display: none;
}
```

which means 
child element having `removeonpagetwoandso` class of elements whose class starts with `paged-`. I think you have problem with your html structure. You HTML must look like as follows:

```
<div class="paged-1">
    <div class="removeonpagetwoandso">
        paged-1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="paged-2">
    <div class="removeonpagetwoandso">
        paged-2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="paged-3">
    <div class="removeonpagetwoandso">
        paged-3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="paged-4">
    <div class="removeonpagetwoandso">
        paged-4
    </div>
</div>
<div class="paged-5">
    <div class="removeonpagetwoandso">
        paged-5
    </div>
</div>
<div class="paged-100">
    <div class="removeonpagetwoandso">
        paged-100
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added my HTML structure. the .paged-2 class is actually inside the body tag. The .removeonpagetwoandso class is inside the body of the HTML. Every page, .page-* changes its number.

Answer (score -2):

**pls try this css**

```
<style> 
div[class^="paged-"]{
 .removeonpagetwoandso{
   display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```