# Material-ui classes name changes on build, adds identifiers to each class name that are overriden by user

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The problem is when used classes={{blah blah}}, it was working fine locally also default material class names were having no identifiers. But on some other machine the css broke, after checking what went wrong I came to know that className generator or something I don't know what, changed my overrides by adding counter number to the classNames I have used.
So now it looks something like this.

[image: check numbers in Mui Stuff!]

Now I don't want to rewrite css again also I can't because this is how you override Mui classes. Production build sucks.

'& .MuiSelect-blah':{
         some css *wooosh
       }

Comment: What version of Material-UI are you using?

Comment: "@material-ui/core": "^4.2.1",

Comment: By default, version 4+ does not add the numeric suffixes to the Mui CSS class names (v3 did). Is the "other machine" using an older version of Material-UI?

Comment: No, Other machine was using same code.

Comment: When you say "it was working fine locally", do you just mean in dev mode? Or was the production build working fine locally?

Comment: yes in dev mode. When i haven't made any build. But some other guy made build and when i pull his code, my css broke too.

Comment: If you do the build yourself, do you see the same behavior? Unless you have code that is specifically changing the classNameGenerator behavior, it seems like the build was done using a older version of Material-UI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201344/discussion-between-sandy-and-ryan-cogswell).

Comment: Hi, did you figure this out eventually?

Answer (score 2):

Since the identifier is only appended on the end of the class name, you can use a [CSS selector to match all elements starting with the class name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13352103/4524257) that you are trying to target.

```css
div[class^='myclass'], div[class*=' myclass']{
    color: #F00;
}
```

Let's say you wan't to target the `MuiOutlinedInput-root` class name.

With a simple helper function `getSelector()`, you could get it done like:

```js
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const getSelector = (className) => `& div[class^='${className}'], div[class*=' ${className}']`;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  input: {
    [getSelector('MuiOutlinedInput-root')]: { // this will generate the selector
      ...
    },
    '& input': {
      ...
    }
  },
}));
```

---

NOTE: [The following syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508490/4524257) is only available on **ES6** and **Babel**

```js
{
    [keyVariable]: value,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in App main file:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { StylesProvider, createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

 const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
   productionPrefix: 'some',
 });

 export default function App() {
    return (
     <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>...</StylesProvider>
   );
 }
```

Comment: After setting this up, do I need a consumer where I use `makeStyles()`? Because this has patially fixed the problem, but still, some parts are broken.