# React CSS class gets override automatically on production server

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am facing a weird CSS issue in my React project. A particular part of the `JSX <div>` has a class applied to it and added some style properties in the main `.css` file of the project. In local development, everything works fine but as soon as the build is created and uploaded to the production server, that particular part of the `JSX <div>` CSS class changes and the styling gets distorted.

Example:

**Original JSX**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: 450,
  },
  margin: {
    height: 100,
  },
}));

const PrettoSlider = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: "red",
    height: 8,
  },
  thumb: {
    height: 24,
    width: 24,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    border: "2px solid currentColor",
    marginTop: -8,
    marginLeft: -12,
    "&:focus,&:hover,&$active": {
      boxShadow: "inherit",
      border: "2px solid #fff407 !important",
    },
  },
  active: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff407",
  },
})(Slider);

const CustomizedSlider = ({
  id,
  abbr,
  type,
  minElig,
  maxElig,
}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(sliderPreviousValue);
  }, [sliderPreviousValue]);


  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        {type === "intervention" ? (
          <ProgressBar max={maxElig} value={sliderValue} />
        ) : null}

        {renderSlider}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Original DOM:**

```
<div class="diabMetr clearfix">
   <span class="diabLabl">Diabetes</span>
   <div class="makeStyles-root-1">
      <span class="MuiSlider-root WithStyles(ForwardRef(Slider))-root-3 MuiSlider-colorPrimary"><span class="MuiSlider-rail WithStyles(ForwardRef(Slider))-rail-8"></span><span class="MuiSlider-track WithStyles(ForwardRef(Slider))-track-7" style="left: 0%; width: 83.3333%;"></span><input type="hidden" value="200"><span class="MuiSlider-thumb WithStyles(ForwardRef(Slider))-thumb-4 MuiSlider-thumbColorPrimary PrivateValueLabel-open-12 PrivateValueLabel-thumb-11" tabindex="0" role="slider" data-index="0" aria-label="pretto slider" aria-orientation="horizontal" aria-valuemax="240" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="200" style="left: 83.3333%;"><span class="PrivateValueLabel-offset-13 MuiSlider-valueLabel WithStyles(ForwardRef(Slider))-valueLabel-6"><span class="PrivateValueLabel-circle-14"><span class="PrivateValueLabel-label-15">200</span></span></span></span></span>
      <div class="valueOuter clearfix"><label class="valueLeft">0</label><label class="valueRight">240</label></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS for this JSX is:**

```
.diabMetr {
        padding-top: 10px;
        span.diabLabl {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 200px;
          text-align: left;
          font-size: 12px;
          line-height: 30px;
          text-align: right;
          @include respond-to(media-xl) {
            width: 120px;
          }
        }
        span.MuiSlider-root {
          width: 100%;
          padding: 0;
          height: 0px;

          .MuiSlider-rail {
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            background: #e8e8e8;
            opacity: 1;
          }
          .MuiSlider-track {
            height: 30px;
            background: #88d479;
            border-radius: 15px;
          }
          .MuiSlider-thumb {
            z-index: 12;
            width: 35px;
            height: 35px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-left: -17px;
            border: #88d479 solid 2px;
            margin-top: -3px;
          }
          .MuiSlider-markLabel.MuiSlider-markLabelActive:last-child() {
            right: 0 !important;
          }
        }
      }

.makeStyles-root-1 {
  width: calc(100% - 220px) !important;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -22px;
}
```

**The DOM changes after build and uploaded to the server:**

```
<div class="diabMetr clearfix">
   <span class="diabLabl">Diabetes</span>
   <div class="jss16">
      <span class="MuiSlider-root jss18 MuiSlider-colorPrimary"><span class="MuiSlider-rail jss23"></span><span class="MuiSlider-track jss22" style="left: 0%; width: 83.3333%;"></span><input type="hidden" value="200"><span class="MuiSlider-thumb jss19 MuiSlider-thumbColorPrimary jss27 jss26" tabindex="0" role="slider" data-index="0" aria-label="pretto slider" aria-orientation="horizontal" aria-valuemax="240" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="200" style="left: 83.3333%;"><span class="jss28 MuiSlider-valueLabel jss21"><span class="jss29"><span class="jss30">200</span></span></span></span></span>
      <div class="valueOuter clearfix"><label class="valueLeft">0</label><label class="valueRight">240</label></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS for the class `.jss16` is:**

```
.jss16 {
    width: 450px;
}
```

***Issue to notice***
Only the class `.makeStyles-root-1` gets replaced with some random class `.jss16` when the build gets uploaded to the server and the CSS changes accordingly, the rest of the JSX remains unchanged. I tried searching for the class `.jss16` everywhere in the code, but it's not found. Also, everything works fine on localhost.

I tried adding the CSS properties to the `.jss16` like this:

```
.jss16 {
  width: 450px;
  width: calc(100% - 220px) !important;
  margin-top: -22px;
  float: right;
}
```

and then re-initiate the uploading process but then instead of `.jss16`, another class is replaced something like `.jss42`. This keeps on repeating and does not work on any new build created.

I also tried the following CSS:

```
.diabMetr + span + div {
  width: 450px;
  width: calc(100% - 220px) !important;
  margin-top: -22px;
  float: right;
},
```

but this also didn't help. The styling of the app still remains distorted (incorrect, not as on localhost).

I spent several hours searching for this but in vain. If anyone can assist me in understanding this error and resolve the same, will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll keep looking into this but it seems similar to what styled-components does when the webpack build is bundled up. It converts any classnames to randomly generated class names by design.

Comment: Try referring to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525586/material-ui-classes-name-changes-on-build-adds-identifiers-to-each-class-name-t

Comment: You are showing us not the jsx, but the generated DOM (this is a bit misleading)

Comment: @MihályiZoltán I forgot to add. Updated now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are quite a few issues with this code. First in `jsx` CSS class is given as `className` as @Max has mentioned in his/her answer.
Another issue is that `@material-ui`'s `makeStyle` doesn't work in this way. The classNames inside the `makeStyle` change to random names in the build stage. This happens to keep the classNames uniques, this is `@material-ui`'s feature. I'd suggest you to read [this @matrial-ui's documentation](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook) about `makeStyles`. And [here](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#examples-3) a code example is provided.

To use makeStyles classes you've to hook it into your component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    color: props => props.color,
  },
});

export default function MyComponent(props) {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      Lorem iosum poder
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Update

According to your `jsx` code, add the styles which you've added in css class `.makeStyles-root-1` in the `useStyles` object. It'll add the styles to the element.
After adding those CSS styles in `useStyles` this object will look like this:-

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: 'calc(100% - 220px) !important',
    float: 'right',
    marginTop: '-22px'

  },
  margin: {
    height: 100,
  },
}));
```

The `root` class will contain those styles and it'll be applied without providing the styles separately from the `CSS` file.

Comment: I updated my code with JSX instead of the DOM. The `<div className={classes.root}>` is what actually gets converted with the random className in the DOM.

Comment: yes.. this happens behind the scene while build. Now the style which you've applied in class `.makeStyles-root-1`, now you can add those styles in the `useStyles ` object in `root` key. I'm updating the answer in few mins.

Comment: One more small help. If I  pass the property `margin` from the CSS `root: {
    width: 'calc(100% - 220px) !important',
    float: 'right',
    marginTop: '-22px'
  },
  margin: {
    height: 100,
  },` as prop to component `<ProgressBar max={maxElig} value={sliderValue} clsmargn={classes.margin}/>`, it creates a new class in the DOM like: `<div class="makeStyles-root-1"> <div class="makeStyles-root-2"> 
      <span class="MuiSlider-root >.....</span> </div>
   </div>`. Can you help explain this behavior pls?

Comment: yes. This is how the `@material-ui` compilation works. It creates new and random class names so that the classes remain unique in each file. Suppose you've created a `root` class in `Component A` and also in `ComponentB` but you've given different styles to the root class in both components. If it doesn't create a new class then both styles will clash and the result will be not what expected. So, it creates a different and unique classNames for each file or better say for each `makeStyls` use.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

I am not sure what component creates the div with "jss16" class, assume it is `ExternalComponent`.

You should add a custom className (assuming ExternalComponent handles this correctly):

```
<ExternalComponent className="myclass">
   ...
</ExternalComponent>
```

this will create a DOM like this:

```html
<div class="jss16 myclass">
    ...
</div>
```

Sou you can create css for `myclass`:

```css
.myclass {
  width: calc(100% - 220px) !important;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -22px;
}
```

#### Explanation

ExternalComponent uses jss to dynamically generate css classes, so you cant rely on the name of the dynamically generated class. In most of the cases, components with custom classes should append props.className to the generated jss like this:

```
return (
    <div className={jssClassname + props.className ? ' ' + props.className : ''}>
        {children}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't reproduce the error because I had some syntax issues, so I wonder if fixing these, the build will behave correctly:

- Add closing `/` to `input`
- Write style's using objects, example `style={{left: '0%', width: '83.3333%'}}`
- Update `class` to `className`
- Update `tabindex` to `tabIndex`

Lastly, if that doesn't help, to make your CSS work, ie `.diabMetr + span + div`, rewrite it to:

`.diabMetr > span + div {}`

or

`.diabMetr > div {}`

Right now, it's not selecting the child element.