# Locating multiple elements by partially equal id/class values

Tags: testcafe

I'm struggling with a thing that may be obvious for some of you. Let's imagine I have an array of HTML elements like:

```
<tr> id=item-1 ... </tr>
<tr> id=item-2 ... </tr>
<tr> id=item-3 ... </tr> etc.
```

What I want to do is to write a TestCafe selector that will find the entire table of elements by id "item-". Can anyone answer how to do this?

A simple

```
NAME_OF_SELECTOR = Selector('tr').withAttribute('id', 'item-');
```

doesn't work that way; it needs the entire name id.

Answer (score 3):

You are already close to what you want to achieve. The [withAttribute method](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/withattribute.html) also accepts regular expressions, which you can use like this:

```js
const myTableRowsSelector = Selector('tr').withAttribute('id', /^item-/);
```

As an alternative, you could also do the following:

```js
const myTableRowsSelector = Selector("tr[id^='item-']");
```

The second example is inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352080/match-all-elements-having-class-name-starting-with-a-specific-string).