# Remove stylesheet only inside react app window

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Image will best describe this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

code sandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/annoying-stylesheet-2gpejc?file=/public/index.html

I'm writing React app inside non react app and their styles interfere with my React app styles.

How do I overwrite `bootstrap-enterprise.css` stylesheet only for the region of my React app without overriding the style rest for the rest of the page (The top app bar is theirs)

Edit:

```css
.App {
  all: revert;
}
```

worked initially, but then I tried it my real usecase (overrding Mui Textfield styling component) and it didn't. i edited the codesandbox for the exact case.

Answer (score 2):

Since your React app is separated from the rest of the app, you could use the [`all` css property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/all/) to reset all the styles inside your React app before to write yours :

```css
/* Affect all the elements under .App */
.App * {
  all: unset
}
```

In your codesandbox, adding it at the top of your `styles.css` seems to work fine.

Comment: this also removes all styles inside my app, i don't want to override the styles on the app itself

Comment: @EliavLouski Well you edited it to give a better example, thank you. By adding `all: unset !important`, it seems to work but the style coming from Mui is gone as well. If it is not what you want, then you could try something like `.App *:not([class*='Mui'])` but you'll have to do a bit of search since this one doesn't work well. I found it here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13352103/9868549

Comment: It does not override MUI styles because they come later